# Terraform explicitly pass multiple provider

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I use terraform for all the infra needs.

All my configuration is stored in Azure KV in say Subscription "DEVOPS". All my infra for testing is created in Subscription "Staging"

Following is my TF code

```
variable name {}
variable location {}
variable tags {}
 
provider "azurerm" {
    subscription_id = "Staging"
    features()
}

provider "azurerm" {
    subscription_id = "DEVOPS"
    features()
    alias = "devopskv"
}

module "resource_group" {
  source = "../modules/azure-resource-group"

    name     = var.name
    location = var.location
    tags     = var.tags
    
    providers = {
        azurerm = azurerm
        azurerm.devopskv = azurerm.devopskv
    }   
}

## Module



data "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name                = "my-kv"
  resource_group_name = "my-kv-rg"
  provider            = azurerm.devopskv
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "name" {
  name         = var.name
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
  provider     = azurerm.devopskv
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_group" {
  name     = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.name.value
  location = var.location
  tags     = var.tags
}
```

**Output expected:**
RG created in Staging subscription Staging with name fetched from KV residing in DEVOPS Subscription.

**Actual Output:**
error:
Resource group "my-kv-rg" is not found.

**Trace Details:**
TF is trying to fetch the KV "my-kv" from subscription "Staging" and not "DEVOPS".

what is wrong on above ?

Comment: Any more updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it.

Comment: What is the reason that you do not respond also do not accept it if it solves your problem? It's simple to mark it if works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use multiple providers in the module, I recommend you set all the providers also inside the module. Take a look at the [link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/providers.html#passing-providers-explicitly). It should be like this:

```
## Module

provider "azurerm" {}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias = "devopskv"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name                = "my-kv"
  resource_group_name = "my-kv-rg"
  provider            = azurerm.devopskv
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "name" {
  name         = var.name
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
  provider     = azurerm.devopskv
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_group" {
  name     = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.name.value
  location = var.location
  tags     = var.tags
}
```

In addition, you also need to set the variables inside the module to accept the input of the root level. If you already have done it, just ignore this advice.

Comment: Really wish there was a clear demonstration in TF docs on how to properly access the providers that are passed in to the module.

Comment: This is against best practise I've provided an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's against terraform best practise to create providers inside of callable modules. A provider must be injected into a module at initialization time. Therefore all provider configurations must be set at the caller and passed in.

If you have caller terraform `main.tf` which calls a complicated module, say one working across multiple clouds, and not only that but working across multiple accounts / subscriptions within those clouds all of the provider configurations are defined at the caller and passed into the module.

```
// main.tf

// aws default, unaliased provider plus an aliased provider with extra config
provider "aws" {}

// an aliased provider with extra config
provider "aws" {
  alias = "connectivity"
  region = "..."
  assume_role = {} // if required
}

// azurerm default, unaliased provider
provider "azurerm" {}

// an aliased provider with extra config
provider "azurerm" {
  alias = "connectivity"
  subscription_id = "..."
}

module "multi-cloud" {
  source = "...?=ref=v1.0.0"
  ...
  providers = {
    azurerm              = azurerm
    azurerm.connectivity = azurerm.connectivity
    aws                  = aws
    aws.connectivity     = aws.connectivity
  }
}
```

Inside the source code for module `multi-cloud` you have to read in these providers. This can be done in any `.tf` file, `main.tf` for example but it's common to see it in the `terraform.tf` or `providers.tf` file, this is purely organizational and terraform doesn't care which file you use.

```
// terraform.tf
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.5.0" // bonus
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=3.59.0"
      configuration_aliases = [
        azurerm.connectivity
      ] 
    }
   aws = {
     source  = "hashicorp/aws"
     version = ">=5.7.0"
     configuration_aliases = [
        aws.connectivity
     ] 
    }
  }
}
```

Now your module source code can utilize the aliases as expected

```
//main.tf
data azurerm_virtual_hub "vhub" {
  provider = azurerm.connectivity
  name                = "example"
  resource_group_name = "example"
}
resource azurerm_virtual_hub_connection "vhc" {
  provider = azurerm.connectivity
  ...
  remote_virtual_network_id = data.azurerm_virtual_hub.vhub.id
} 
resource azurerm_resource_group "rg" {
  name     = "example"
  location = "example"
}
```

I've used the `azurerm` provider as an example but the `aws` one works just the same. The default unalised provider is used to create the rg and I was able to pull network data from a different subscription (analogous to account in aws) and create a network peering to it.